# Error while starting eclipse spring boot. - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have download eclipse spring boot but it is not starting. On running STS.exe, it is throwing error. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Tried to Google that error message, specifically that return code?

Comment: In the folder `D;\sts_sclipse\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\configuration` you will find some file with extention `.log`, check it.

Comment: Got it. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Comment: Then may be you need a 32-bit JVM

Comment: My JVM is 64-bit and STS is 32-bit. I am downloading 64-bit spring boot

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the JVM version (32/64 bit) you use matches the eclipse version (32/64 bit).

My Java Version is 64-bit JVM

and Spring Boot Eclipse Version is 32-Bit

If you get same check the version of both JVM and Spring Boot Eclipse Version both should be 32-bit or 64-bit

Java version can check by command prompt.

```
C:\Users\GHAR>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

To check Spring Boot Eclipse verison, go to

```
D:\STS_64BIT\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\

open .eclipseproduct file in the folder,
check package= parameter
```

64-bit look like this

```
package=spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64.zip
```

32-bit look like this

```
package=spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32.zip
```

I hope this will help some one future.